# how to get pom.xml content in jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins, pom.xml

I want to parse artifact names and their versions in jenkins according to parsing I need to trigger other builds before the current project as pre-build. How can I do this in jenkins, I couldn't find any plugin that can provide pom's artifacts as a variable. Is there any way to do this without writing any script code?

Comment: I'm sorry - can you explain a little bit further?

Comment: Ok, let I have project A and related job in jenkins and in its pom there is <dependency> tag <groupID>com.B</groupId><artifactId>B</artifactId><version>1.0</version>  I need to parse the element dependency and its other elements in order to trigger Job B with the version which is written in the pom.xml of the A project before the build of the A. So the job B should be build before the build of A when I click the build button of the A. I wish I could be able the explain my problem :)

Answer (score 1):

short answer: NO not without coding your own plugin.

take the quickstart archetype of jenkins plugin and in your perform method of your generated plugin:

```
@Override
public boolean perform( AbstractBuild build, 
            Launcher launcher,
            BuildListener listener) {
```

you can access information this way:

```
for (Iterator iterator = build.getProject().getAllJobs().iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
    Job currentJob = (Job) iterator.next();             
    if (currentJob instanceof MavenModuleSet) {
        MavenModuleSet mms = (MavenModuleSet) currentJob;
                for (Iterator iter = mms.getModules().iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
                       MavenModule currentModule = (MavenModule) iter.next();
```

currentModule is your module from your root pom.xml, keen in mind the name in jenkins **currentModule.getName** is ***NOT*** the artifact name as of maven specs but the **groupid:artifactid** instead.

Answer (score 0):

you can get it by taking POM variables as Jenkins Environment variables.
and then use $variablename to access the pom content anywhere.